# RxJS Keep Subject/Observable Subscription Active After Error

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Is there a way to prevent a subscription to a stream (either observable or subject) from completing after calling the error function on the observable/subject?

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();
subject.subscribe(function(){alert("OnNext")}, function(){alert("OnError")});

var next = document.querySelector("#next").addEventListener('click', function(){
  subject.next();
})
var error = document.querySelector("#error").addEventListener('click', function(){
  subject.error();
});
```

From what I understand, calling `subject.error()` completes the event stream. So keeping the observable open would break the contract of the Observable object. So how can I handle the lifecycle of the observable in such a way that would recreate the subscription after an error occurs? Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UHAwTuNHDNhUtIilExlT?p=preview) demonstrating the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply said, you can't. At least not with Subjects.

Subjects have internal state and when they emit or receive `error` notification they [mark themself as stopped](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subject.ts#L72) and will never ever emit anything.

Otherwise, you could use `catch()` or `retry()` operators that resubscribe to their source Observable but this wouldn't help you when using Subjects.